# problem of (double)quote--choosing char by glyphs

Tags: fonts, fontspec, font-encodings

I use `fontenc`, `fontspec` and `xelatex` to load the custom font.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{xunicode}  
\setmainfont[Mapping=Tex-Text]{Warnock Pro}
```

But I have some problem about choosing char by using `\char`. The `\char"201C` is different than just type ``. `` displays correctly as what it is in glyphs. But `\char"201C` is very similar to `\textquotedblleft` (but a little bit different). That is, \char"201C is not belong to typefaces "Warnock Pro". Also, if I just type “, it is also similar to `\textquotedblleft`.

How to output a char by specifying \char"xxx of custom loaded font?

That is, if possible, I don't want to use `[Mapping=Tex-Text]`, and just want to type quote, or other char, such as α directly. Most chars can be displayed right. But some of them (especially quoted-related char) can't be showed right.

--UPDATE
Some chars, such as ‡ or †, it won't be displayed no matter I type † or \char"2020. (no matter I use Mapping=Tex-Text or not). Do I need to add some other parameters?

--UPDATE 2
I found out the problems happends due to I use the package `\usepackage{xeCJK}`. However, I need it to set up English/Forein language seperately. I seems it would make \char"xxx displays the font belongs to `\setCJKmainfont`.

By `xeCJK`, the char\"201C should use non-CJK font. But it seems it still use CJK-font now (even though I use `\xeCJKsetcharclass{"2000}{"2FFF}{0}`). But if I turn of xeCJK (`\makexeCJKinactive` then it displays correctly)

--UPDATE 3
I add the following testing code. It seems `xeCJK` can't work correctly?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKromanfont{Verdana}
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
--\char"201C --``--“--‘‘--\char"60--\textquoteleft\\
%output: verdana--times("60)--verdana--verdana--times--verdana
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
--\char"201C --``--“--‘‘ --\char"60--\textquoteleft\\
% output: verdana, Times ("201C)--verdana--verdana--times("2018)--verdana
\xeCJKsetcharclass{"0}{"2FFF}{0} %same
--\char"201C --``--“--‘‘ --\char"60--\textquoteleft\\
\xeCJKsetcharclass{"0}{"2FFF}{1} %same
--\char"201C --``--“--‘‘ --\char"60--\textquoteleft\\
\makexeCJKinactive %all in roman
--\char"201C --``--“--‘‘ --\char"60--\textquoteleft\\
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: To be clear: you want to remap the character associated with this font to a character from a different font?

Comment: Sorry for not clear. I mean, if doublequote mark in glyph is char"201C, then, type `\char"201C` is different than just typing \`\`. That is, \`\` is correct. `\char"201C` displays double quote mark, but this mark is not belong to Warnot Pro's font.

Comment: Would changing the " character in the input stream to be an active character that expands to `` (or, maybe, '', depending on whether the next char is a space) be an option?

Comment: The problem bothers me because, when I use `\char"xx`, I will get the right char with wrong font. The problem is not a really problem, in fact. But for single/double quote, the different char make the text looked inconsistency sometimes.

Comment: @Kuang-LiHuang: You should update your `xeCJK` package. See also [xeCJK messes with punctuation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36878/) and [Linebreak and \enquote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43583).

Answer (score 6):

**Never** use inputenc with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. **Never**.

The option is actually `Mapping=tex-text` (but the uppercase seems to work too), or better use `Ligatures=TeX`, as this will work with lualatex too.

I don't have your font but \char"201C should work. If it doesn't then either your are doing something curious in the rest of your document, or the font is corrupt, or you have more then one version of the font. Compile this document on the command line with `xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" and then check in the terminal and in the log-file the pathes of the fonts.

```
\XeTeXtracingfonts=1

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Warnock Pro}
\begin{document}
`` ^^^^201c \char"201C
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I remove inputenc.  However, the output is still something wrong. I can get the correct font by using [Mapping=Tex-Text]+`` only. [Mapping=Tex-Text]+\char"201C will get a double quote mark, but not belong to Warnock Pro.  If I remove [Mapping=Tex-Text] (Warnock Pro doesn't provide Ligatures=TeX), then `` won't get double quote of font Warnock Pro (it looks like the font cmr10 or others). The font is correct (if I remove [Mapping] then it displays right).  Thank you

Comment: Compile my example (exactly this example!) and put the pdf + the log-file somewhere on the net for inspection.

Comment: @Ulrike Thank you. I got the problem, and update my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't send code snippets. I have neither the time nor the will to build a test case for your problem. Make a small, complete example that demonstrates the problem. Try to use fonts generally available. Use only ASCII input, input the problematic chars like I did it above with ^^^^ and \char.

Comment: @Ulrike Sorry for bothering you. I put a small example and updated my question again. In my openion, all single/double quote etc. should be regarded as a non-CJK font. But only the last one line (inactive xeCJK) shows the correct output.  Thank you very much!

Comment: xecjk sets `\XeTeXcharclass` of 201C to 2 and inserts a font change between the classes 0 and 2. You can avoid the font change with `\XeTeXcharclass"201C=0` but it can have side effects and at my opinion the behaviour of xecjk is at least a misconception, if not a bug. Notify the author.