# XeTeX, fontspec and Garamond

Tags: xetex, fontspec, cyrillic, garamond

I've got the opportunity to play with a machine with some premium fonts installed. I ran some experiments with XeTeX and e.g. Palatino Linotype, which worked, but for some reason cyrillic breaks with Garamond Premier Pro. The result may be downloaded [here](http://www-verimag.imag.fr/~monniaux/download/essai_garamond_cyrillic.pdf).

UPDATE: It turns out the machine had two versions of Garamond Premier Pro installed, one of which apparently has faulty Cyrillic support even though it advertises cyrillic in `otfinfo -s`. I disabled this version and everything now works fine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers={OldStyle},Ligatures{Common},Contextuals=Alternate]{Garamond Premier Pro}

\begin{document}
Queue stop acte effet shelfful shelf{\null}ful παιδείαὫ $\pi\alpha\phi\Omega$ Черникова ---
\end{document}
```

Comment: The link is not found. What is the question here?

Comment: I would say either your font is corrupt or you have two versions. Check with \XeTeXtracingfonts/-vv option of xdvipdfmx the fonts your example use. See my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15188/problem-of-doublequote-choosing-char-by-glyphs

Comment: If you have found a solution, consider adding it as an answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: This looks 'too localised' to me

Comment: @Joseph: While the specific fonts involved are certainly local the problem itself is rather common. Two versions of the same font (or two fonts with the same name) are the most probable cause when fonts in xetex do "funny" thing. That's why it took me only some seconds to write the answer.

Comment: Also note that otfinfo (or any similar program) merely tells us that the font "claims to have" a feature, which may be in the form of a very minimal table. For example, one font with the sups feature may have only numerals, and another one may also have ascii letters. I don't believe there is any enforced standard as to what an Open Type feature is required to include, whether or not the font has a technical problem.

Answer (score 5):

`\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` helped me trace the problem. It turns out that this machine had two versions of Garamond Premier Pro installed. I disabled one (which perhaps had faulty Cyrillic support, even though it advertised it in `otfinfo -s`…) and now everything is ok.

Comment: A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the input works perfectly with the free `ebgaramond` package as well using either of `xelatex` or `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ebgaramond]{newtx}
\begin{document}
Queue stop acte effet shelfful shelf{\null}ful παιδείαὫ
$\pi\alpha\phi\Omega$ Черникова ---
\end{document}
```

[image: russian]

Comment: The original question was asked 12 (count them, twelve) years ago. It would be nice if SE had a method for moderators to "obsolete" old questions that are no longer pertinent, I but I do not think that exists.